# How to extract an array of hashes out of an existing text file?

Tags: ruby, parsing, erb

I've got kind of a messy situation. I am in the process of migrating a bunch of data that was created in a now-defunct static site generator ([webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/)), which has a lot of data stored in quasi-ERB template files.

I'm trying to write some Ruby to parse through these files, grab what I need, and then write them into my new applications data files.

The problem I am encountering is that I don't have a lot of normalization in the existing files, and matching against some of the patterns is tricky.

For example, each "event" (this is for a tech conference website) has a `_sponsors.txt` file that contains the information for the sponsors for that particular event, constructed of an array of hashes. These arrays aren't always named exactly the same thing, but they're generally similar.

This is a snippet of one of the files:

```
<% @psponsors = [
{ :image => 'ca_technologies.png', :name => 'CA Technologies', :link =>     'http://www.ca.com/fr', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'puppetlabs.png', :name => 'PuppetLabs', :link => 'https://puppetlabs.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'microsoft_azure.png', :name => 'Microsoft Azure', :link => 'http://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_CC=200618989', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
] %>
<% if @psponsors.empty? %>
<i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='<%= File.join('/',@eventhome,'/sponsor') -%>'>Be the first to sponsor!</a></i>
<% end %>
<% @psponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
<a href="<%= sponsor[:link] %>"><img border="1" alt="<%= sponsor[:name] %>" title="<%= sponsor[:name] %>" width="<%= sponsor[:width] %>" height="<%= sponsor[:height] %>" src="<%= File.join('/',@eventhome,"logos/#{sponsor[:image]}") %>" /></a>
<% end %>
<h1>Gold sponsors</h1>
<% @gsponsors = [
{ :image => 'normation.png', :name => 'Normation', :link => 'http://www.normation.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'gandi.png', :name => 'Gandi.net', :link => 'https://www.gandi.net', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'xebialabs.png', :name => 'XebiaLabs', :link => 'http://www.xebialabs.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'redhat.png', :name => 'Red Hat', :link => 'https://www.redhat.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'delphix.png', :name => 'Delphix', :link => 'http://delphix.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
{ :image => 'chef.png', :name => 'Chef', :link => 'http://chef.io', :width => '100px', :height => '100px' },
] %>
```

When I attempt to read in the whole file and match between the outside parameters I'm looking for, I end up getting a bunch of matches I don't want. My current workaround is to simply read each line, and set the state if the line matches the right start, then keep reading it in, and then break when I hit the end. This seems like it's completely non-delightful, and I'm sure I'm missing a much more elegant way to do this.

Comment: So is what you want to pull `@psponsors` and `@gsponsors` out of this file?

Comment: Correct. The problem is, in some of the files, it won't be `@psonsors`, it might be `@msponsors` or `@ssponsors`. But generally speaking, if I can figure out how to do it somewhat generically with this sample I can figure out how to make it work with the outliers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to parse these files, why don't you try executing them instead? Just append some code to dump these (or all: `instance_variables.each { |varname| ...`) instance variables as JSON to stdout or something similar, and try running that through ERB interpreter.

Comment: Hmm. It's a thought. The issues I see with it are a) there are about 40-50 of them, all formatted slightly differently and messy, so it might be messy to add code to them, but b) this step is actually part of a much larger migration process I'm writing that which parses a lot more files/data for each event on the filesystem, and I was hoping to make this a one-op type of activity - write one big migration tool, rather than piecemeal it; we attempted to do it one bit at a time previously and a lot of stuff got lost :(

Answer (score 0):

What about try `nokogiri` and `xpath` like this?

**erb_template.erb**

```
<% @psponsors = [
    {:image => 'ca_technologies.png', :name => 'CA Technologies', :link => 'http://www.ca.com/fr', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'puppetlabs.png', :name => 'PuppetLabs', :link => 'https://puppetlabs.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'microsoft_azure.png', :name => 'Microsoft Azure', :link => 'http://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_CC=200618989', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
] %>
<% if @psponsors.empty? %>
    <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://localhost'>Be the first to sponsor!</a></i>
<% end %>
<% @psponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
    <a href="<%= sponsor[:link] %>"><img border="1" alt="<%= sponsor[:name] %>" title="<%= sponsor[:name] %>" width="<%= sponsor[:width] %>" height="<%= sponsor[:height] %>" src="<%= File.join('/', @eventhome, "logos/#{sponsor[:image]}") %>"/></a>
<% end %>
<h1>Gold sponsors</h1>
<% @gsponsors = [
    {:image => 'normation.png', :name => 'Normation', :link => 'http://www.normation.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'gandi.png', :name => 'Gandi.net', :link => 'https://www.gandi.net', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'xebialabs.png', :name => 'XebiaLabs', :link => 'http://www.xebialabs.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'redhat.png', :name => 'Red Hat', :link => 'https://www.redhat.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'delphix.png', :name => 'Delphix', :link => 'http://delphix.com', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
    {:image => 'chef.png', :name => 'Chef', :link => 'http://chef.io', :width => '100px', :height => '100px'},
] %>
<% @gsponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
    <a href="<%= sponsor[:link] %>"><img border="1" alt="<%= sponsor[:name] %>" title="<%= sponsor[:name] %>" width="<%= sponsor[:width] %>" height="<%= sponsor[:height] %>" src="<%= File.join('/', @eventhome, "logos/#{sponsor[:image]}") %>"/></a>
<% end %>
```

**process**

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'nokogiri'
require 'erb'

@eventhome = ""

path = File.join("./erb_template.erb")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(ERB.new(File.read(path)).result(binding))

links = doc.xpath("//a[./img]")

export = links.each_with_object({}) do |element, h|
  h[element["href"]] = element.first_element_child["title"]
end
```

**output**

```
# {
#   "http://www.ca.com/fr" => "CA Technologies",
#   "https://puppetlabs.com" => "PuppetLabs",
#   "http://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_CC=200618989" => "Microsoft Azure",
#   "http://www.normation.com" => "Normation",
#   "https://www.gandi.net" => "Gandi.net",
#   "http://www.xebialabs.com" => "XebiaLabs",
#   "https://www.redhat.com" => "Red Hat",
#   "http://delphix.com" => "Delphix",
#   "http://chef.io" => "Chef"
# }
```

Comment: Hmm. Am I missing the part where I can see if they are psponsors or gsponsors, etc? I think I can hack this though!